# Google recaptcha not working with Ajax Call codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, recaptcha

I have intigrated recaptcha in to my codeigniter project. But its not functioning when I use AJAX pass.

here is the one which works fine:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'register/login123' ?>" method="post">
<?php echo $widget;?>
<?php echo $script;?>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

and here is the ajax call, which recaptcha fail

```
<form method="post">
  <?php echo $widget;?>
  <?php echo $script;?>
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit_id"/>
```

javascript for this is,

```
$("#sub_btn").click(function() {  
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'register/login123' ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {    
        alert(msg);                 
       }
});
```

}

Can Anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: How does controller with recaptcha code look like? What are `$widget` and `$script`? There is no `#sub_btn` in forms. You missed to post important part.

Comment: the  first one which i mentioned is the working code, but second one, which uses ajax wont work. The variables are coming from recaptcha library.

Comment: What network console says? Any JS bugs there?

Comment: All other things work except recaptcha. In the controller  $recaptcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');   is getting empty value. That is the problem.

Comment: What is view-source in first and what is in second example (not code, but html output - edit your question if you must and add those). Also Try [this tut](http://avenir.ro/integrating-googles-recaptcha-in-codeigniters-form-validation-the-callback-way/) and see if it fits your existing code.